# TYPO3 - override Core\Routing\UrlGenerator

Tags: class, typo3, overriding

I want to override function doGenerate() in this class, but it's not possible to xclass this class.
Alternatively, I tried Helmut Hummel's solution in typo3-config-handling, where he uses a class_alias, like this:

`class_alias(\Helhum\TYPO3\ConfigHandling\Xclass\ConfigurationManager::class, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Configuration\ConfigurationManager::class);`

but no luck either:

'PHP Warning:  Cannot declare class TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator, because the name is already in use in /home/ahkalbert/vendor/netklaar/typo3-routing/res/php/autoload-include.php on line 2'

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Please add some background why you want to override this class. Maybe there are better solutions.

Comment: I want to be able to manipulate the decoded and encoded url, like this was possible in ext realurl. Therefore I Xclassed Classes/Routing/PageRouter and Classes/Routing/UrlGenerator. The former works, the latter not (yet) - at the moment I just replace the UrlGenerator file, but that's of course not how it should be 'fixed'.

Comment: There is a hook in the `SlugHelper` for this purpose which allows you to freely adjust the generated slug. Then you don't need to do anything at runtime. If that doesn't help please add more details about what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't do the trick: I want to be able to manipulate the whole url, not just the part that is added by the slughelper.